# getting the same error every time with with DES Encryption java code

Tags: java, security, netbeans, encryption, cryptography

I'm using NetBeans, and I'm having a problem with the following code:
A lot of mistakes sorry!! i'm new here and i update the code with last edit but still i gets the same error

```
    package org.owasp.crypto;

import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

/**
 * @author Joe Prasanna Kumar
 * This program provides the following cryptographic functionalities
 * 1. Encryption using DES
 * 2. Decryption using DES
 * 
 * The following modes of DES encryption are supported by SUNJce provider 
 * 1. ECB (Electronic code Book) - Every plaintext block is encrypted separately 
 * 2. CBC (Cipher Block Chaining) - Every plaintext block is XORed with the previous ciphertext block
 * 3. PCBC (Propogating Cipher Block Chaining) - 
 * 4. CFB (Cipher Feedback Mode) - The previous ciphertext block is encrypted and this enciphered block is XORed with the plaintext block to produce the corresponding ciphertext block 
 * 5. OFB (Output Feedback Mode) - 
 *
 *  High Level Algorithm :
 * 1. Generate a DES key
 * 2. Create the Cipher (Specify the Mode and Padding)
 * 3. To Encrypt : Initialize the Cipher for Encryption
 * 4. To Decrypt : Initialize the Cipher for Decryption
 * 
 * Need for Padding :
 * Block ciphers operates on data blocks on fixed size n. 
 * Since the data to be encrypted might not always be a multiple of n, the remainder of the bits are padded.
 * PKCS#5 Padding is what will be used in this program 
 * 
 */

public class DES {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DES strDataToEncrypt = new DES(System.in);
                DES strCipherText = new DES(System.in);
                DES strDecryptedText = new DES(System.in);

        try{
        /**
         *  Step 1. Generate a DES key using KeyGenerator 
         * 
         */
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

        /**
         *  Step2. Create a Cipher by specifying the following parameters
         *          a. Algorithm name - here it is DES
         *          b. Mode - here it is CBC
         *          c. Padding - PKCS5Padding
         */

        Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        /**
         *  Step 3. Initialize the Cipher for Encryption 
         */

        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey);

        /**
         *  Step 4. Encrypt the Data
         *          1. Declare / Initialize the Data. Here the data is of type String
         *          2. Convert the Input Text to Bytes
         *          3. Encrypt the bytes using doFinal method 
         */
                System.out.print( "Type some data for the program: " );
                String input = strDataToEncrypt.nextLine();
        //strDataToEncrypt = "Hello World of Encryption using DES ";
        byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = strDataToEncrypt.getBytes();
        byte[] byteCipherText = desCipher.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt); 
        strCipherText = new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteCipherText);
        System.out.println("Cipher Text generated using DES with CBC mode and PKCS5 Padding is " +strCipherText);

        /**
         *  Step 5. Decrypt the Data
         *          1. Initialize the Cipher for Decryption 
         *          2. Decrypt the cipher bytes using doFinal method 
         */
        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKey,desCipher.getParameters());
         //desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKey);
        byte[] byteDecryptedText = desCipher.doFinal(byteCipherText);
        strDecryptedText = new String(byteDecryptedText);
        System.out.println(" Decrypted Text message is " +strDecryptedText);
        }

        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgo)
        {
            System.out.println(" No Such Algorithm exists " + noSuchAlgo);
        }

            catch (NoSuchPaddingException noSuchPad)
            {
                System.out.println(" No Such Padding exists " + noSuchPad);
            }

                catch (InvalidKeyException invalidKey)
                {
                    System.out.println(" Invalid Key " + invalidKey);
                }

                catch (BadPaddingException badPadding)
                {
                    System.out.println(" Bad Padding " + badPadding);
                }

                catch (IllegalBlockSizeException illegalBlockSize)
                {
                    System.out.println(" Illegal Block Size " + illegalBlockSize);
                }

                catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException invalidParam)
                {
                    System.out.println(" Invalid Parameter " + invalidParam);
                }
    }

    private DES(InputStream in) {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private String nextLine() {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private byte[] getBytes() {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

And the new error is:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at org.owasp.crypto.DES.<init>(DES.java:132)
    at org.owasp.crypto.DES.main(DES.java:46)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What's might be the problem?

update#1

Answer (score 1):

Use `DES.class.getName()` instead of `DES.getClass().getName()`

- `getClass()` is a member function and can be invoked only on instance of a class, not the type of the class
- `DES` represents a class, not an instance of the class DES.

Comment: What's the next question? My bets are on `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. :P

Comment: i change it but still gets the same error

Comment: Did you replace-all? How about updating the question with stack trace?

Comment: run:
des.DES
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at des.DES.<init>(DES.java:139)
 at des.DES.main(DES.java:53)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: I think somebody was right four minutes ago.

Comment: That's because your constructor throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. Tip: Use a debugger. It Helps :-[